# Configurable Joint, wrong target position

Tags: unity-game-engine

When using configurable joint, you have the options to set a target position which the body is trying to get to by using the X,Y,Z drive. Which should work with the normal position system when both primary axis and secondary axis are untouched.

However, when I set the Target Position to say (1, 0, 0). What I expect is the body goes to the right by 1 unit.
What I get instead is the body goes to the LEFT by 1 unit. Can someone explain to me why is this happening?

Picture:

Show1: When the target position is (0, 0 ,0)
[image]

Show2: When the target position is (1, 0 ,0)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The target position is in the reference frame of the object with the ConfigurableJoint. What you're essentially saying is that the virtual spring starts at (1,0,0) relative to the object. The virtual spring at that location is then drawn to the ConnectedAnchor which in your case is at (0,0,0).